# Number of arrangements with constraints

Tags: combinatorics

We have N students with roll numbers from $1$ to $N$. We need to make them stand in a line L(eg. '3 4 2 1') according to the following constraints:

- There is at least one pair of indices $(i,j)$ such that $i < j$ and $L[i] > j, L[j] > i$.
- M more constraints of type $(X_i, V_i)$.

  - Constraint $i$ $(1 ≤ i ≤ M)$ requires $L[X_i] = V_i$.

Count number of ways of making students stand in a line.
Eg:
$N = 3, M = 0$
Then there is only one way to make them stand which is $(3,2,1)$ and required $(i, j) $ is $(1,2)$.